# can i add in a string symbols from word python

Tags: python, symbols

I want to put this symbols in my string ▀ ▄ █ but when i run the program they turn into letters...
here's my program:

```
print"""
 █▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█
 █         █           █▀▀
 █         █           █▀
 █ Slim    █           █
 █ stone   █  Zika     ███
 █▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█  town     █▀
 █ Meju    █           █
 █     ▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
 █▄▄▄▄▄█▀  ▄█   █        """
```

Is it becaus im in python 2.7?

Comment: ... I don't see them turning into letters. Tried both in IPython and saving that code to a file and executing with python. Can you show the output you get? Anyway, keep in mind that not every terminal is able to display all characters, so maybe its the terminal's fault.

Comment: "Letters" -- like 'a', 'b', 'K' or more like 'Č', 'Ã', 'Ö'?

Comment: If you use python2.7 you *must* specify an encoding in the file. Add a `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` comment at the beginning of the file(otherwise you get an error like `File "strange.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file strange.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details`
`). however I can print the text correctly in python2.7

Comment: I have thath but still it wont print me the ▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to unicode the string by adding `u` before the string, example `u"foo"`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print u"""
 █▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█
 █         █           █▀▀
 █         █           █▀
 █ Slim    █           █
 █ stone   █  Zika     ███
 █▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█  town     █▀
 █ Meju    █           █
 █     ▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
 █▄▄▄▄▄█▀  ▄█   █        """
```

prints:

```
> python foo.py

 █▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█
 █         █           █▀▀
 █         █           █▀
 █ Slim    █           █
 █ stone   █  Zika     ███
 █▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀█  town     █▀
 █ Meju    █           █
 █     ▄▄▄▄█▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄█
 █▄▄▄▄▄█▀  ▄█   █

>
```